# On applying proguard by enabling minifyEnabled = true, I am getting warning messages due to itextpdf library classes

Tags: java, android, itext, proguard, obfuscation

I wanted to apply `proguard` to my Apk, so in `build.gradle`(module:app) file
I made changes, due to which i got warnings generated related with `itextpdf` library.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      debuggable false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
  }
```

### problem Error Generated

> build failed  38 s 838 ms Starting Gradle Daemon  2 s 983 ms Run
>   build 34 s 60 ms Load build   2 s 48 ms Configure settings    1 s 430 ms
>   Configure build   13 s 54 ms Calculate task graph 186 ms Run tasks    18 s
>   701 ms Unmanaged thread operation #-1 (Tasks limiter_1)   10 ms null
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryptor: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.cms.CMSException  com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryptor:
>   can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.cms.jcajce.JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryptor: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.cms.RecipientInformation 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryptor: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.cms.Recipient
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.DEROutputStream
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.DEROctetString 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.DERSet 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.RecipientInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.DERSet 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.EncryptedContentInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.pkcs.PKCSObjectIdentifiers 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.EncryptedContentInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.EnvelopedData
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.ContentInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.pkcs.PKCSObjectIdentifiers 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.ContentInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.TBSCertificateStructure
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.IssuerAndSerialNumber
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.TBSCertificateStructure
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Integer
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.IssuerAndSerialNumber
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.RecipientIdentifier
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.KeyTransRecipientInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.DEROutputStream     class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.DERSet
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.EncryptedContentInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Set
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.EnvelopedData
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.ContentInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.KeyTransRecipientInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.TBSCertificateStructure
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.IssuerAndSerialNumber
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.DEROctetString 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.RecipientIdentifier
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedData 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.cms.RecipientInformationStore
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedData 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.cms.RecipientInformation 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedData 
>   org.spongycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.crypto.AESCipher: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.crypto.AESCipher: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.crypto.AESCipher: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.crypto.BlockCipher
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.crypto.AESCipher: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.crypto.AESCipher: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.crypto.AESCipherCBCnoPad: can't find referenced
>   class org.spongycastle.crypto.engines.AESFastEngine
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.crypto.AESCipherCBCnoPad: can't find referenced
>   class org.spongycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.crypto.AESCipherCBCnoPad: can't find referenced
>   class org.spongycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.crypto.AESCipherCBCnoPad: can't find referenced
>   class org.spongycastle.crypto.BlockCipher 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.crypto.AESCipherCBCnoPad: can't find referenced
>   class org.spongycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.MD2$Digest
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.MD2
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.MD5$Digest
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.MD5
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.SHA1$Digest
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.SHA1 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest: can't find
>   referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.SHA224$Digest 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.SHA224
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest: can't find
>   referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.SHA256$Digest 
>   javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.XPathType
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.Reference 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.C14NMethodParameterSpec
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMSignedInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMKeyInfoFactory
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfoFactory
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class org.apache.xml.security.utils.Base64
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dom.DOMStructure
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.TransformParameterSpec
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.XPathFilter2ParameterSpec
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.XPathType$Filter 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.XPathType
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.XPathFilter2ParameterSpec
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.DigestMethod
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.DOMSignContext
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLObject 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.DOMSignContext
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMUtils
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMSignedInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMSignedInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.Reference 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMSignedInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class  javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfoFactory
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.X509Data
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfoFactory
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyValue
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature: can't find referenced
>   class  org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1TaggedObject 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Set 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.AttributeTable
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.Attribute
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.cms.ContentInfo 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.tsp.TimeStampTokenInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.jce.provider.X509CertParser
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Set 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.jce.X509Principal
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1OutputStream
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.DERSequence 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.DERSet   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7:
>   can't find referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1OutputStream
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.DERSet   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7:
>   can't find referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.tsp.MessageImprint
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.cert.ocsp.BasicOCSPResp
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.cert.ocsp.SingleResp 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.cert.ocsp.CertificateID
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.operator.DigestCalculator
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.cert.ocsp.CertificateID
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1TaggedObject
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1OctetString 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ocsp.BasicOCSPResponse
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class
>   org.spongycastle.tsp.TimeStampToken
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.tsp.TSPException
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.tsp.TimeStampRequestGenerator
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.tsp.TimeStampRequestGenerator
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle: can't find
>   referenced  class org.spongycastle.asn1.cmp.PKIFailureInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.tsp.TimeStampResponse
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.tsp.TimeStampToken
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.tsp.TimeStampTokenInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.tsp.TimeStampRequestGenerator
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.tsp.TimeStampRequest
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.tsp.TimeStampResponse
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.cmp.PKIFailureInfo 
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.tsp.TimeStampToken
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.tsp.TimeStampTokenInfo
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAInfoBouncyCastle: can't find
>   referenced class org.spongycastle.tsp.TimeStampTokenInfo
>   io.sqlc.SQLitePlugin: can't find referenced method
>   'java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView keySet()' in
>   library class java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap   there were 770
>   unresolved references to classes or interfaces.    there were 1
>   unresolved references to library class members.    Exception while
>   processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings
>   first.

## Efforts made to resolve the issue

### #In proguard-android.txt file I added this lines

## proguard configuration for iText

```
-keep class org.spongycastle.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.spongycastle.**

-keep class com.itextpdf.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.itextpdf.**

-keep class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.** { *; }
-dontwarn javax.xml.crypto.dsig.**

-keep class org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.**

-keep class javax.xml.crypto.dom.** { *; }
-dontwarn javax.xml.crypto.dom.**

-keep class org.apache.xml.security.utils.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.xml.security.utils.**

-keep class javax.xml.crypto.XMLStructure
-dontwarn javax.xml.crypto.XMLStructure
```

production build Apk must be generated

Comment: Please provide the github link of the library for which you are getting the error.Also let us know what is the version of the library that you are using.Better o post the gradle file here.

Comment: Did you resolve this?